# Java, Text on Image, update

Tags: java, image, swing, text

I want to write some text on a image(BufferedImage), but when the text is updated the new text is written over the old one, e.g. all numbers are written in same place, Can someone help.
 i'm usins this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prove extends JPanel {
    int size =  800;
    private BufferedImage sc ;
    JLabel label ;
    private int counter =0 ;

    public Prove()
    {       
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.setSize(2*size, size);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try{ sc = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/ser.jpg"));     
            label =new JLabel(new ImageIcon(sc));
            this.add(label);
        }catch(IOException e){}


    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0,0, getWidth(),getHeight());        //prapavijen 

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        paintScore(g2);
    }

    public void paintScore(Graphics g2)
    {

        if(sc != null)
        {
            Graphics gi = sc.createGraphics();
            gi.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
            String r = counter+"";
            gi.drawString(r, 20, 20);
            counter ++;
            this.repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(500);}
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
            System.out.println(counter);
        }   

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Prove();

    }



}
```

Comment: FYI: don't use Thread.sleep in the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) and don't call repaint() in paintComponent.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). (needs a `main()`) *Ignore - my bad* 2) For the image, use one from the JRE or generate it in code. 3) Agree with @GuillaumePolet 4)  Don't use a `File` for embedded application resource (WAG) use an `URL`. 5) There is no reason to draw the text directly on the image.  Simply draw the image to the component `Graphics` instance then draw the string to the same `Graphics`. 6) Only one blank line is required for white-space in source, don't use 3! 7) The frame should conform to the size of components, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @AndrewThompson there is actually a main (only problem is that the image is a File, but I ran it earlier)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Right you are.  Comment (crudely) edited.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: the 5th point was actually the solution to my problem. For other point, I am new here. Thank you, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to draw the text directly on the image. Simply draw the image to the component `Graphics` instance then draw the string to the same `Graphics`.

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing the text to the same position, it is bound to overwrite

```
gi.drawString(r, 20, 20);
```

You will need to change the vertical coordinate if you want the new text to appear below the old one

Comment: I want to update the text on the same place, after each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You must keep an unmodified copy of the original image. Try this pseudocode:

```
BufferedImage img1 = loadImage();
```

And in your paint code:

```
BufferedImage img2 = createEmptyImage( img1 ); // same size, mode and depth
Graphics g = img2.getGraphics();
try {
    g.draw( img1 ); // background
    g.drawString(); // render text on top of it
} finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `dispose()` (pseudo-code or otherwise) of any `Graphics` object you explicitly create.

Comment: Yes, I understood that this is the logic of solution, but I don't know how to implement it in the right way. Can you please write more detailed code ?

Comment: @ironwud: Sit down, try it out and let us know if you have an error or something that we can help with. There is no way for us to inject the knowledge into your brain without some effort on your side.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I tried, but i either get just image without text or text over text, can you please write some code that after each iteration would write new text(updated) without changing position ?

Comment: You probably used `img1` to draw the final result in `paintScore()`. You must use `img2` because it contains the image and the text (`img1` is *never* modified)